# PHPUnit deletes database records for Yii unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, yii, phpunit

I am running unit tests in Yii using phpunit. All tests are passing, but it leaves me with one record in the database when I expected to see three, one for the fixture when testing login and two from ARO saves I call when testing member registration.

I am doing this in a separate database dedicated to testing only. Is this something I should be concern with or typical behavior possibly related to teardown?

The record for "testReg" remains in the database after this code even though it is saved before "testReg2". If I comment out that save, "testReg2" remains. If I comment out those two, the fixture data remains.

Here is the test:

```
class UserTest extends CDbTestCase
{
public $fixtures=array(
    'users'=>'User',
);

/**
 * Valid user can login to backend
 * @return void
 */
public function testBackendUserLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();
    $model->attributes = array('username'=>'member', 'password'=>'password');
    $this->assertTrue($model->validate(array('username', 'password')));
    $this->assertTrue($model->login());
}

/*
 * Only logged in super-admin or sub-admins with approved accounts may create new members
 * @return void
*/
public function testBackendMemberRegister(){
    $member=new Member();
    $member->register(array(
        'username'=>'testReg',
        'password'=>'password',
    ));
    $member2=new Member();
    $member2->register(array(
        'username'=>'testReg2',
        'password'=>'password',
    ));
}
```

}

Fixture:

```
return array(
    'user'=>array(
        'username'=>'member',
        'password'=>'$2a$08$U/z5X4Y1Ok4g20t6DWSwqezgNylpqdjKmrsMFBJDvLqQmOKMG6SvO',
        'created'=>'04-05-2013 00:00:00',
        'modified'=>'04-05-2013 00:00:00',
    )
);
```

The method which calls the ARO save is in class User. Member class extends User class.

```
public function create(array $submission){
    $this->attributes=$submission;
    $this->hashPassword();
    $submission['password']=null;   //for safety
    if($this->save()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your PK isn't set to Auto Increment? I also notice you are calling $userModel->register() as opposed to $userModel->create(). I'm assuming that's by design, but you might check that register is acting appropriately.

Comment: Yes on the PK and yes on the register() by design. Member model with the register() method extends the User model with the create() method. I will be adding an Admin class which has a different workflow.

In the unit test, I created assertions which check for the existence of the newly created record. They all pass when I run the test. So far everything works on the frontend, so I want to attribute this to  setup or teardown, although I cannot find it documented.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I ran into a similar problem with a model saving it's record over a previous entry. If I recall correctly it had to do with the PK not being set to AI but I had marked the PK as 'safe' in the model rules. I can't think of another reason why this would happen.. Your code looks fine to me and fixtures / unit tests should leave all data together once the test completes - in this case you should see all the users you create as well as your fixture data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an assertion to check for record existence after register() and it passed. Everything's working on the frontend so for now I'm attributing it to teardown, although I cannot find explicit documentation.